# how to use flex datagrid lockedcolumncount for two columns?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

How do you use flex datagrid `lockedColumnCount` for two columns?

For example, I have 5 columns of datagrid columns: A, B, C, D and E. I want the A and E columns to be locked and the remaining columns able to be scrolled horizontally.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use [lockedColumnCount](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridBase.html#lockedColumnCount), do something like this:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myDataGrid" lockedColumnCount="2" >
```

The DataGrid always locks the leftmost columns.  There is no way to lock the leftmost column and the rightmost column.  (As far as I know this isn't even possible in Excel).  You'll have to extend the DataGrid to do this; although logistically I'm not relly seeing how it'd work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could put two datagrids side by side.

So basically you have one hbox, with two datagrids in it.

The first with columns A thru D and the second with just E.

Set lockedColumnCount=1 on both and set the horizontalScrollPolicy=false on the second.

I havnt tried this and could be completely wrong, but hope this helps someone.